How do I interpret and fix this error I get when executing an OpenACC program using NVIDIA nvc compiler?
I translated a parallel C program with OpenMP pragma directives into a C program with OpenACC pragma directives to run it on a GPU by removing the original OpenMP pragmas and adding in OpenACC directives where I thought parallelization was possible. The serial version, without the OpenMP or OpenACC pragma directives, works perfectly fine, and so does the OpenMP version. I am getting a strange error when executing the OpenACC version with the same nvc compiler I used for the other two versions.
Its a large machine learning program so I am only mentioning the functions that I added OpenACC pragma directives to: 
Function 1:
void function1(double const *x, double *const *W, double *D, int num_out, int num_features, double alpha, int R)
{
    int j, k;

#pragma acc kernels loop
    for (j = 0; j < num_out; j++)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < num_features; k++)
            sum += (W[j][k] - x[k]) * (W[j][k] - x[k]);
        D[j] = sum;
    }

    double d_min = INFINITY;
    int d_min_idx = -1;

#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(min : d_min)
    for (j = 0; j < num_out; j++)
    {
        if (D[j] < d_min)
        {
            d_min = D[j];
            d_min_idx = j;
        }
    }

    int from_node = max(0, d_min_idx - R);
    int to_node = min(num_out, d_min_idx + R + 1);

#pragma acc kernels
    for (j = from_node; j < to_node; j++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < num_features; k++)
            W[j][k] += alpha * (x[k] - W[j][k]);
    }
}

Function 2:
void function2(double **X, double *const *W, int num_samples, int num_features, int num_out, double alpha_min)
{
    int R = num_out >> 2, iter = 0;
    double alpha = 1.f;
    double *D = (double *)malloc(num_out * sizeof(double));

#pragma acc data copyin(X[0 : num_samples][0 : num_features], W[0 : num_out][0 : num_features]) create(D[0 : num_out])
    {
        for (; alpha > alpha_min; alpha -= 0.01, iter++)
        {
            for (int sample = 0; sample < num_samples; sample++)
            {
                const double *x = X[sample];
                kohonen_update_weights(x, W, D, num_out, num_features, alpha, R);
            }
            if (iter % 10 == 0 && R > 1)
                R--;
        }
    }
    free(D);
}

To compile the serial version of this program, without OpenACC pragma directives, I use the following command: 
$ nvc -Minfo=all -o program program.c
And get the following results, as expected:
Test 1 completed in 0.01334 sec
Test 2 completed in 0.006111 sec
Test 3 completed in 0.003211 sec
(Note: Calculated times include: creating test sets, training model and writing files to disk.)

I expected similar results from when I compiled and executed the OpenACC version as well, with the -acc flag.
HOWEVER
When I compile the program with the OpenACC pragma directives using the following commad: 
$ nvc -acc=gpu -gpu=cc89 -Minfo=all -o program program.c
And run the executable file, I get the below error: 
Accelerator Fatal Error: This file was compiled: -acc=gpu -gpu=cc35 -gpu=cc50 -gpu=cc60 -gpu=cc60 -gpu=cc70 -gpu=cc75 -gpu=cc80 -
Rebuild this file with -gpu=cc89 to use NVIDIA Tesla GPU 0
 File: /proj/build/23C/Linux_x86_64/rte/accel-uni/build/Linux_x86_64/../../src/cuda_fill.c
 Function: __pgi_uacc_cuda_fill:98
 Line: 44

Some contextual information if that might help: 
$ nvidia-smi
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.171.04             Driver Version: 535.171.04   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070        Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   29C    P8               5W / 200W |    340MiB / 12282MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1551      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          106MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1804    C+G   ...libexec/gnome-remote-desktop-daemon      154MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1899      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         65MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

nvc --version
nvc 24.1-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp znver4

nvaccelinfo
CUDA Driver Version:           12020
NVRM version:                  NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  535.171.04  Tue Mar 19 20:30:00 UTC 2024

Device Number:                 0
Device Name:                   NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070
Device Revision Number:        8.9
Global Memory Size:            12568887296
Number of Multiprocessors:     46
Concurrent Copy and Execution: Yes
Total Constant Memory:         65536
Total Shared Memory per Block: 49152
Registers per Block:           65536
Warp Size:                     32
Maximum Threads per Block:     1024
Maximum Block Dimensions:      1024, 1024, 64
Maximum Grid Dimensions:       2147483647 x 65535 x 65535
Maximum Memory Pitch:          2147483647B
Texture Alignment:             512B
Clock Rate:                    2520 MHz
Execution Timeout:             Yes
Integrated Device:             No
Can Map Host Memory:           Yes
Compute Mode:                  default
Concurrent Kernels:            Yes
ECC Enabled:                   No
Memory Clock Rate:             10501 MHz
Memory Bus Width:              192 bits
L2 Cache Size:                 37748736 bytes
Max Threads Per SMP:           1536
Async Engines:                 2
Unified Addressing:            Yes
Managed Memory:                Yes
Concurrent Managed Memory:     Yes
Preemption Supported:          Yes
Cooperative Launch:            Yes
Default Target:                cc89


EDIT 1:
Results from -Minfo=all argument in the compilation command:
     65, Loop carried dependence of D-> prevents parallelization
         Loop carried backward dependence of D-> prevents vectorization
         Complex loop carried dependence of x->,W->-> prevents parallelization
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
         65, #pragma acc loop seq
         68, #pragma acc loop vector(128) /* threadIdx.x */
             Generating implicit reduction(+:sum)
     65, Generating implicit copyout(D[:num_out]) [if not already present]
         Generating implicit copyin(W[:num_out][:num_features],x[:num_features]) [if not already present]
     68, Loop is parallelizable
     77, Generating implicit firstprivate(num_out,d_min_idx)
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
         77, #pragma acc loop seq
             Generating reduction(min:d_min)
     77, Generating implicit copy(d_min) [if not already present]
         Generating implicit copyin(D[:num_out]) [if not already present]
     82, Accelerator restriction: induction variable live-out from loop: d_min_idx
     90, Complex loop carried dependence of x->,W->-> prevents parallelization
         Accelerator serial kernel generated
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
         90, #pragma acc loop seq
         92, #pragma acc loop seq
     90, Generating implicit copyin(x[:num_features]) [if not already present]
         Generating implicit copy(W[.I0000:min(num_out,(R+d_min_idx)+1)-.I0000][:num_features]) [if not already present]
     92, Complex loop carried dependence of x->,W->-> prevents parallelization
kohonen_som_tracer:
    104, Generating copyin(X[:num_samples][:num_features],W[:num_out][:num_features]) [if not already present]
         Generating create(D[:num_out]) [if not already present]



EDIT 2:
The entire program to reproduce the results, with independent clauses added:
// Version using OpenACC to offload computations to GPU
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifndef max
#define max(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif
#ifndef min
#define min(a, b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

double _random(double a, double b)
{
    int r = rand() % 100;
    return ((b - a) * r / 100.f) + a;
}

int save_nd_data(const char *fname, double **X, int num_points, int num_features)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "wt");
    if (!fp)
    {
        char msg[120];
        sprintf(msg, "File error (%s): ", fname);
        perror(msg);
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_features; j++)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "%.4g", X[i][j]);
            if (j < num_features - 1)
                fprintf(fp, ",");
        }
        if (i < num_points - 1)
            fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

void kohonen_get_min_1d(double const *X, int N, double *val, int *idx)
{
    val[0] = INFINITY; // initial min value

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) // check each value
    {
        if (X[i] < val[0]) // if a lower value is found
        {                  // save the value and its index
            idx[0] = i;
            val[0] = X[i];
        }
    }
}

void kohonen_update_weights(double const *x, double *const *W, double *D, int num_out, int num_features, double alpha, int R)
{
    int j, k;

#pragma acc kernels loop independent // added independent
    for (j = 0; j < num_out; j++)
    {
        double sum = 0;
#pragma acc loop reduction(+ : sum) // added this entire pragma
        for (k = 0; k < num_features; k++)
            sum += (W[j][k] - x[k]) * (W[j][k] - x[k]);
        D[j] = sum;
    }

    double d_min = INFINITY;
    int d_min_idx = -1;

// Suggested code from Mat Colgrove on Stack overflow question
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78392570/how-do-i-interpret-and-fix-this-error-i-get-when-executing-an-openacc-program-us/78409755#78409755
#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(min : d_min)
    for (j = 0; j < num_out; j++)
    {
        if (D[j] < d_min)
        {
            d_min = D[j];
        }
    }
#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(min : d_min_idx)
    for (j = 0; j < num_out; j++)
    {
        if (D[j] == d_min)
        {
            d_min_idx = j;
        }
    }

    int from_node = max(0, d_min_idx - R);
    int to_node = min(num_out, d_min_idx + R + 1);

#pragma acc kernels loop collapse(2) independent
    for (j = from_node; j < to_node; j++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < num_features; k++)
            W[j][k] += alpha * (x[k] - W[j][k]);
    }
}

void kohonen_som_tracer(double **X, double *const *W, int num_samples, int num_features, int num_out, double alpha_min)
{
    int R = num_out >> 2, iter = 0;
    double alpha = 1.f;
    double *D = (double *)malloc(num_out * sizeof(double));

#pragma acc data copyin(X[0 : num_samples][0 : num_features], W[0 : num_out][0 : num_features]) create(D[0 : num_out])
    {
        for (; alpha > alpha_min; alpha -= 0.01, iter++)
        {
            for (int sample = 0; sample < num_samples; sample++)
            {
                const double *x = X[sample];
                kohonen_update_weights(x, W, D, num_out, num_features, alpha, R);
            }
            if (iter % 10 == 0 && R > 1)
                R--;
        }
    }
    free(D);
}

void test_circle(double *const *data, int N)
{
    const double R = 0.75, dr = 0.3;
    double a_t = 0., b_t = 2.f * 3.14; // theta random between 0 and 2*pi
    double a_r = R - dr, b_r = R + dr; // radius random between R-dr and R+dr
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        double r = _random(a_r, b_r);     // random radius
        double theta = _random(a_t, b_t); // random theta
        data[i][0] = r * cos(theta);      // convert from polar to cartesian
        data[i][1] = r * sin(theta);
    }
}

void test1()
{
    int j, N = 500;
    int features = 2;
    int num_out = 50;

    // 2D space, hence size = number of rows * 2
    double **X = (double **)malloc(N * sizeof(double *));

    // number of clusters nodes * 2
    double **W = (double **)malloc(num_out * sizeof(double *));

    for (int i = 0; i < max(num_out, N); i++) // loop till max(N, num_out)
    {
        if (i < N) // only add new arrays if i < N
            X[i] = (double *)malloc(features * sizeof(double));
        if (i < num_out) // only add new arrays if i < num_out
        {
            W[i] = (double *)malloc(features * sizeof(double));
            // preallocate with random initial weights
            for (j = 0; j < features; j++)
                W[i][j] = _random(-1, 1);
        }
    }

    test_circle(X, N);                         // create test data around circumference of a circle
    save_nd_data("test1.csv", X, N, features); // save test data points
    save_nd_data("w11.csv", W, num_out,
                 features);                              // save initial random weights
    kohonen_som_tracer(X, W, N, features, num_out, 0.1); // train the SOM
    save_nd_data("w12.csv", W, num_out,
                 features); // save the resultant weights

    for (int i = 0; i < max(num_out, N); i++)
    {
        if (i < N)
            free(X[i]);
        if (i < num_out)
            free(W[i]);
    }
}


double get_clock_diff(clock_t start_t, clock_t end_t)
{
    return (double)(end_t - start_t) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

/** Main function */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    clock_t start_clk = clock();
    test1();
    clock_t end_clk = clock();
    printf("Test 1 completed in %.4g sec\n",
           get_clock_diff(start_clk, end_clk));
    printf(
        "(Note: Calculated times include: creating test sets, training "
        "model and writing files to disk.)\n\n");
    return 0;
}

EDITS:

Added the results from the -Minfo=all argument in the compilation command, in case it has relevant information.
Added the entire program to help reproduce the output.

How do I approach solving this error ? Is there anything I am missing, or should refer to ?
Thank you in advance for your help!

It looks like openacc runtime you are using doesn’t support your GPU

I have been using this gpu for all my openacc programs. This is the first time I am seeing this error.

The error is telling you that an internal compoent in the PGI openacc runtime doesn’t have code for your GPU architecture. Maybe your other code doesn’t pass through that particular function. I would upgrade to a newer version of the openacc tools and runtime (or reinstall everything) if you have the possibility to do so. Something is broken

I reinstalled the nvidia drivers, the nvidia HPC SDK (that has the internal components and nvc compiler). It still gives me the same error. I edited the question to include the results from the -Minfo=all argument from my compilation command. Do you think there is some usefull information in the compilation information to detect what could be the issue?

Can you post a full reproducing example?  I typically I see this error if the runtime can't find the CUDA driver or was not compiled for the correct target.  Though since nvaccelinfo can detect the device, the OpenACC runtime should as well.  Also the error output suggests that the binary was compiled with "-gpu=ccAll", but that's not what you show.  The problem is likely something specific to your system (I'm just not sure what yet), but I'd like to try an reproduce it here, in case it's a problem with your program.

Also, try removing "-gpu=cc89" and let the compiler auto-detect the device.  Probably wont help, but worth a try.

Note that per the compiler feedback messages, the compiler isn't able to parallelize these loop due the to potential aliiasing of the pointers and the "live-out" variable.  These shouldn't cause the runtime error, but I'll post an answer with a fix to the code to get it to parallelize.

@MatColgrove i posted the full program to help reproduce the output. I compiled it wihtout the -gpu=cc89 tag and it still yielded the same error. I agree, I thiink there is soem issue with the pointer aliasing, just dont know how to fix it when using openac directives. I would like to make minimal changes to the original serial C program, when adding in the the openacc directives to make it gpu-accelerated.

The good news is that I was able to reproduce the error.  However it seem to only occur on Ada (cc89) and only with your program.  I tried several other OpenACC programs without issue.  I'm not seeing anything special about the program that would cause this so not sure what's wrong.  I did see a linker warning on one system that may or may not be related, but if it is, then the problem is likely with our linker script which embeds the GPU binary in the exe.  I submitted a bug report to engineering, TPR#35605.  Still trying to find you a work around, but no luck yet.

Thank you so much for your help. I wonder if it works on other GPU architectures o not. I only have access to this one NVIDIA 4070 in my PC at the moment that I use for prototyping GPU code. I intend to run this program on a larger cluster, which'll most likely have server-level GPUs, eventually so I would just like to know if it'll work on different GPU archtiectures.

FYI, we believe we have this issue (TPR#35605) fixed in the 24.7 release of NVHPC.

While this may not fix the runtime error you're seeing, I've updated your code so it will parallelize the loops.  You need to add "independent" to the "kernels" region to tell the compiler to ignore the dependencies.  Due to C allowing pointers of the same type to alias the same data, the compiler must assume that they do.  Hence, it can't automatically parallelize the loops.
Also as written, "d_min_idx" will likely give a incorrect result.  Unfortunately you can both find the min value and it's index in the same parallel loop.  Hence it needs to be split into two loops.  I have it set to find the first index that matches the min value in the even multiple indices have the same value.
 #include <math.h>

void function1(double const *x, double *const *W, double *D, int num_out, int num_features, double alpha, int R)
{
    int j, k;

#pragma acc kernels loop independent
    for (j = 0; j < num_out; j++)
    {
        double sum = 0;
#pragma acc loop reduction(+:sum)
        for (k = 0; k < num_features; k++)
            sum += (W[j][k] - x[k]) * (W[j][k] - x[k]);
        D[j] = sum;
    }

    double d_min = INFINITY;
    int d_min_idx = -1;

#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(min : d_min)
    for (j = 0; j < num_out; j++)
    {
        if (D[j] < d_min)
        {
            d_min = D[j];
        }
    }
#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(min : d_min_idx)
    for (j = 0; j < num_out; j++)
    {
        if (D[j] == d_min)
        {
            d_min_idx = j;
        }
    }

    int from_node = max(0, d_min_idx - R);
    int to_node = min(num_out, d_min_idx + R + 1);

#pragma acc kernels loop collapse(2) independent
    for (j = from_node; j < to_node; j++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < num_features; k++)
            W[j][k] += alpha * (x[k] - W[j][k]);
    }
}

Compiler feedback messages:
% nvc -c -w -acc -Minfo=accel test.c
function1:
      8, Loop is parallelizable
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
          8, #pragma acc loop gang /* blockIdx.x */
         12, #pragma acc loop vector(128) /* threadIdx.x */
             Generating reduction(+:sum)
      8, Generating implicit copyout(D[:num_out]) [if not already present]
         Generating implicit copyin(W[:num_out][:num_features],x[:num_features]) [if not already present]
     12, Loop is parallelizable
     21, Generating implicit firstprivate(num_out)
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
         21, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
             Generating reduction(min:d_min)
     21, Generating implicit copy(d_min) [if not already present]
         Generating implicit copyin(D[:num_out]) [if not already present]
     29, Generating implicit firstprivate(d_min,num_out)
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
         29, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
             Generating reduction(min:d_min_idx)
     29, Generating implicit copy(d_min_idx) [if not already present]
         Generating implicit copyin(D[:num_out]) [if not already present]
     41, Loop is parallelizable
         Generating implicit copyin(x[:num_features]) [if not already present]
         Generating implicit copy(W[from_node:to_node-from_node][:num_features]) [if not already present]
     43, Loop is parallelizable
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
         41, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) collapse(2) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
         43,   /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x collapsed */

